# Reference request: banach and locally convex spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces

I recently started reading Vector Measure, by Diestel, and I'm quite amazed about some beautiful theorem characterizing Banach spaces. I defenitely want to get more in dept with the subject, and thus I'm here asking for a reference. I would like a book which doesn't fear to use nets and filters, and an advanced book, my background in basic functional analysis is the sum of Brezis and Rudin's books.

I found out that two books seems very beautiful, at a first look: sequences and series in Banach spaces, and locally convex spaces by Jarchow. What do you think?

Thank you